# How to order columns with fluent api in dotnet core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

[image]

I split fluentApi into class,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new WarehouseConfiguration());
```

Comment: You're showing a non-existing method. There is no API for this. Why would you want to enforce column order? It's not necessary and later changes may require a table rebuild.

Comment: I don't think it will recreate the table but I didn't try . 
HasColumnOrder()  --> I want the equivalent of this method in the current version.

Comment: This is not the place to post change requests.

Comment: You are asking for functionality which does not exist currently (the latest official EF Core release). I think it will be included in the upcoming EF Core 6.0, but you have to wait for it to be released.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok . Understood so finally Can I do with HasAnnotation method ?

Comment: @GertArnold Where I change request ?  Isn't fluent api database change tools?

Comment: It's not enough I guess. Annotations store some metadata, but there must be some processor/service to use/apply it. Hence w/o infrastructure support (which is the actual feature, not the annotation) there is nothing you could do. Except if you want to write all that infrastructure code yourself.

Comment: Quick googling shows this OS package https://github.com/premchandrasingh/EFCoreColumnOrder, which claims to address the problem in question for EFC 3.1, but w/o trying it I have no idea if it really does and if it works with EFC 5.0

Comment: Ivan Stoev oke thanks . if I want solve this problem. I will Attribute [Column(Order=1)] :) but now, I don't this  .

Comment: As Ivan said, the attribute won't do anything. EF-core isn't (yet) wired to listen to it. I think the only thing you can do is change the generated migration code (if you use migrations). Better still is to just ignore the order unless you have a compelling reason to enforce it. There really aren't many reasons to want this.